# send two variable in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send two variable by AJAX to PHP,

```
    $('#add_news').on( 'click',function () {
var news_subject = $('#news_subject').val();
var news_content = $('#summernote_1').code();

console.log(news_subject);
console.log(news_content);

jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/news/add_news",
                        data: "news_subject="+ news_subject + "news_content="+ news_content,
                        type: "POST",
                        success:function(data){ 


                                }
                        });
```

but while submitted this,
i get like below,

news_subject:Testnews_content=Hello,

How can i seperate two variable news_subject and news_content, so that my PHP controller can get post value and send to DB,
Currently it go as one **variable** new_subject and **value** is --Testnews_content=Hello.

I assume something wrong in data: but i dont know how to send two variable in one data,
Can you help,

Thanks,

Comment: You forgot an `&` in the data line... change it to this: `data: "news_subject="+ news_subject + "&news_content="+ news_content`. Notice the `&` before `news_content`...

Answer (score 7):

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/news/add_news",
            data: 
            {
             news_subject:news_subject,
             news_content: news_content
            },
             type: "POST",
             success:function(data){ }
           });
```

use it like this

Answer (score 4):

You can send two variables within ajax you are on right way but just missed **&** character within your code that bind the value with other variables

Your code.

```
data: "news_subject="+ news_subject + "news_content="+ news_content,
                                      ^^
```

You need lil' update over here..

```
data: "news_subject="+ news_subject + "&news_content="+ news_content,
                                      ^^^
```

and it can also be achieved as

```
jQuery.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/news/add_news",
             data: 
                 {
                  news_subject:news_subject,
                  news_content: news_content
                 },
             type: "POST",
             success:function(data){ 

             }
           });
```

Comment: @rjcode you can accept anyone's answer so it might be considered it as solved issue. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/news/add_news",
                        data: {"news_subject": news_subject,"news_content": news_content},
                        type: "POST",
                        success:function(data){ 


                                }
                        });
```

(or)

```
data: "news_subject="+ news_subject + "&news_content="+ news_content,
```